# Fatal error: Call to undefined method ADODB_oci8::select()

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, oci8

im trying to upgrade an old system from old CI to latest CI.
found this error when i changed query function from:

```
$query = "select * from tableA";
return $this->db->execute($query);
```

into:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('tableA')
                  ->get();
return $query->result();
```

the first one work fine. but the 2nd one display this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ADODB_oci8::select()

hope someone can help me

**edited this is the db config**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";//.rand(2,3);
$db['default']['username'] = "username";
$db['default']['password'] = "pass";
$db['default']['database'] = "dbname";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "oci8";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Comment: could you please post the result of $this->db->last_query() for both 1st and 2nd method?

Comment: got the same result for last_query() sir.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ADODB_oci8::last_query()

Comment: Can you show us your database config? How are you loading the database?

Comment: i've add the db config. pls help